# Kiel traduki "Touchdown"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Saluton!
Mi rete nur trovis la tradukon "alteriĝo" por la angla vorto "touchdown" el la usona futballudo. 
Mi pensas ke "alteriĝo" iel bonas, sed eble ie troviĝas pli bona vorto.
Dankon!

Answer (score 1):

*Alteriĝo* is landing a plane.

Benson has *celtrafo* (also here https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/celtrafo).

As a side note, when speaking Esperanto with my kids, didn't want to say *usona futbalo* all the time, so in our house we called it *kradpilko* (gridiron.)

Comment: I am german. Don't you also say _touchdown_ when a plane lands. So _alteriĝo_ is understandable, but not good.

I like _celtrafo_!

Comment: Eble aliaj mensoj funkcias alie, sed por mi, la du esprimoj estas malsamaj. En tiu okazo mi ne tuj komprenis kiel "alterigxo" rilatis al kradpilko (usona futbalo). "Mi penso kudri" ne estas "I thought sew". :-)